# How can I monitoring and intercepting all dynamic AJAX Requests and resend them again?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, xmlhttprequest, monitoring

How can I monitoring and intercepting all dynamic AJAX Requests and resend them again?
How can I do this?

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.realSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(value) {

    this.addEventListener("error", function(){
        /* 
           Need Resend It By XMLHttpRequest In Here
           All Resend Request Are Dynamic Generate
           Such As "new XMLHttpRequest(this).send()"
           Use AJAX Are Also OK
        */
    }, false);
    this.realSend(value);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Obviously it will work for AJAX calls made after the execution of this snippet, so you will need to execute it as soon as possible.

I don't know exactly what is your use case, but be aware that a failed request can fail 1 million more times if the cause of the error is not fixed. With this code each retry is equal to the previous failed one.

Please also note that you will need to make some modifications to access the response of a nested request once successful.

```js
// PROXY 'open' INSTEAD OF 'send' SO YOU CAN CAPTURE REQUESTS EARLY.
XMLHttpRequest.prototype._open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

// WE NEED TO TRACK RETRY NUMBER PER REQUEST TO AVOID INFINITE LOOPS.
XMLHttpRequest.prototype._maxRetry = 5;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype._currentRetry = 0;

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function open(...args) {

    if (!this._currentRetry) {
        console.log('REQUEST CAPTURED.');
    }

    this.addEventListener('error', () => {
        // ABORT PREVIOUS REQUEST.
        this.abort();

        // CHECK NUMBER OF RETRIES.
        if (this._currentRetry >= this._maxRetry) {
          console.log('MAX RETRY REACHED.');
          return;
        }

        console.log(`RETRYING ${this._currentRetry} of ${this._maxRetry}.`);

        // CREATE NEW REQUEST INSTANCE.
        const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        
        // COPY UPDATED RETRY NUMBERS TO NEW INSTANCE.
        req._maxRetry = this._maxRetry;
        req._currentRetry = this._currentRetry + 1;
        req.responseType = this.responseType;
        
        // SEND NEW REQUEST USING PREVIOUS REQUEST ARGUMENTS.
        req.open(...args);
        req.send();
    });

    // CALL ORIGINAL 'open' METHOD.
    this._open(...args);
};

const test = new XMLHttpRequest();

test.open('GET',  'https://asfashdg');
test.send();
```

Comment: No No No, my problem is all received requests is fully dynamic with unknown xmlhttprequest open() and send(). Can I get and resend unknown request?